# Issue with clicking elements, that were added to page with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm having trouble with clicking events on elements, that were rendered by .html() function of jQuery.
Here's my code I'm testing with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <input type="submit" name="loginButton" id="loginButtonID"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#loginButtonID').click(function() {
            $('#content').html('<button name="loginButton" id="newPasswordID">New Button</button>')
        });
        $('#newPasswordID').on('click', function() {
            alert("alert");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, at the very beginning, I render a button with `id="loginButtonID"`. I have `.click()` event on it, that creates in its turn another button by `.html()` (since `.text()` will return just HTML-code of that button) with `id="newPasswordID"` and for that button I have another event `.on()` as it should be (not `.click()`), but that event just doesn't work. So the question is: how to make that `.on()` event work for the second button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `#newPasswordID` element doesn't exist *as of when you try to hook the event*. So since when you do `$("#newPasswordID")` it doesn't match anything, no handler is set up.

You can either do that after you render that element, or you can hook the event on some container that the element goes in (looks like `#content`) and use event delegation:

```
$("#content").on("click", "#newPasswordID", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Since that really hooks `click` on `#content`, but then only fires it if the event travelled through an element matching `#newPasswordID`, it doesn't matter whether `#newPasswordID` exists as of when you hook up the event or not.

Comment: Thanks for explanation :) Worked well!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#content').html(
    $('<button />').attr('name',"loginButton")
        .attr('id', "newPasswordID")
        .click(function() {
            alert('alert');
        })
);
```